# Why Leaflet can't download the right tiles in WMTS?

Tags: leaflet, wmts

I use basemap.at and try to show with Leaflet. It can always download some tiles, but other parts of the tileset have wrong request.

This is my code in index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI=" crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM=" crossorigin=""></script>

...
...


    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>

    <script>

        const map = L.map('map').setView([48.2, 16.4], 14);
    
        const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://maps{s}.wien.gv.at/basemap/bmaphidpi/normal/google3857/{z}/{y}/{x}.jpg', {
            maxZoom: 19,
            subdomains: [0, 1, 2, 3],
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.basemap.at">basemap.at</a>'
        }).addTo(map);

    </script>
```

[image: This is what I see]

the tiles are not displayed diagonally on the map.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Which are these "other parts of the tileset have wrong request"?

Comment: @TomazicM I updated my post with more specic details.

Answer (score 4):

The subdomains for basemap.at are: `"maps","maps1", "maps2", "maps3", "maps4"` not `maps0` as you wrote.

So each time you try to call that tile you get an error, as you can see on the console. I guess that leaflet is taking one of each of the 4 subdomains you provided, which is why 1 tile out of 4 is missing.

You can easily correct your code by removing the 0 from your subdomains definition.

You can look at these sources for more information on how to use the Austrian basemaps:

https://www.mapsmarker.com/news/how-to-use-basemap-at-within-leaflet-maps-marker

https://basemap.at/#hilfe